# Parse Excel variables into powershell

Tags: excel, azure, powershell

I am trying to create a powershell that will grab the varibles from an excel sheet and then add them to the powersehll command.

in the excel sheet i have 3 columns i am interested in the data from (Name , resourcegroup, location)
And then for each line with this i want it to parse into into the varible field for the powershell
I have created the powershell to do what i need but it would be better if it could loop through and pull this as I am just running the command again with different machine info manually added from the excel.

With @Theo Help

I am working with this version of the script now

```
Import-Csv -Path 'c:\scripts\vmtest.csv' | ForEach-Object {
# combine the VMName with suffix '-Snapshot'
$snapshotName = $vm.name + "-Snapshot" 
$SnapshotStorage = "Azure-Snapshots" 


$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup -Name $_.Name

# using splatting for better readability
$configParams = @{
    SourceUri    = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id
    Location     = $_.location
    CreateOption = 'copy'
}
$snapshot = New-AzSnapshotConfig @configParams

New-AzSnapshot -Snapshot $snapshot -SnapshotName $snapshotname -ResourceGroupName $snapshotstorage
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as you have commented, you now have the data stored in a CSV file that might look something like this:

```
 Name,ResourceGroup,Location
 PRD-ITM001,SJAVIRTUALMACHINES,uksouth
 TST-GRSSQL001,SJAVIRTUALMACHINES,uksouth
```

it has become very simple to import that data and loop through the records like below:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'c:\scripts\vmtest.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # combine the VMName with suffix '-Snapshot'
    $snapshotName    = '{0}-Snapshot' -f $_.Name 
    $SnapshotStorage = "Azure-Snapshots" 

    $vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup -Name $_.Name

    # using splatting for better readability
    $configParams = @{
        SourceUri    = $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id
        Location     = $_.Location
        CreateOption = 'copy'
    }
    $snapshot = New-AzSnapshotConfig @configParams

    New-AzSnapshot -Snapshot $snapshot -SnapshotName $snapshotName -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup
}
```

Note that the above code assumes your CSV uses the (default) *comma* as delimiter character. If in your case this is some other character, append parameter `-Delimiter` followed by the character the csv uses.

- Inside a ForEach-Object {..} loop, the [$_  automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#_) references the current record from the csv
- I used [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for better readability of the code. This helps on cmdlets that take a long list of parameters and eliminates the use of the backtick.

Comment: This worked for me - i had to amend a couple bits but it did the job Thankyou !

Comment: Although I though this worked its getting the wrong vm name to source disk it appears to be picking the wrong previous vm name and assign it to the wrong source disk ? Im not sure how to add a screenshot here ? [url=https://ibb.co/vXL98yN][img]https://i.ibb.co/J3rZP6Y/azuresnapshot.jpg[/img][/url]

Comment: <a href="https://ibb.co/vXL98yN"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/J3rZP6Y/azuresnapshot.jpg" alt="azuresnapshot" border="0"></a> it works a part from its getting the wrong snapshot name to actual source disk ?

Comment: @wolfmaster74 please show the forst 3 or 4 lines of the csv you are importing as copy/pasted from notepad. It looks like it is not using the _comma_ as delimiter character as I tried to explain in the note

Comment: It looks like the below                                                                             Name,ResourceGroup,Location
PRD-ITM001,SJAVIRTUALMACHINES,uksouth
TST-GRSSQL001,SJAVIRTUALMACHINES,uksouth

Comment: @wolfmaster74 Aha, so your csv only has three columns, not four and the column names are different from what you said earlier. I'll update my answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above shared requirement, we understood that you want to pull the values of `ResourceGroupName`, `VMName` from the excel sheet & also you want to use those values in the script further.

- Using **PSExcel** Module, We have written the below **PowerShell Script** which will pull the ResourceGroupName, VMName from excel & it will run `Get-AzVM` Cmdlet.
- Before running the below PowerShell script , run the below cmdlet [Save-Azcontext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/save-azcontext?view=azps-7.1.0) cmdlet it will saves the current authentication information for use in other PowerShell sessions.

```html
   Connect-AzAccount
   Save-AzContext -Path C:\test.json
```

**Here is the PowerShell script:**

```html
$currentDir = "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" ##pass the path of the PSexcel Module 
    Import-Module $currentDir"\PSExcel"  
    Import-AzContext -Path C:\test.json ##passing the azcontext file path which was saved earlier
    $ExcelFile = "Give here the path of the current folder where scripts are stored"
    $objExcel = New-Excel -Path $ExcelFile  
    $WorkBook = $objExcel|Get-Workbook  
    
    ForEach($Worksheet in @($Workbook.Worksheets)){ 
     
     $totalNoOfRecords = $Worksheet.Dimension.Rows  
     $totalNoOfItems = $totalNoOfRecords-1
     # Declare the starting positions first row and column names 
     $rowNo,$colResourceGroupName = 1,1  
     $rowNo,$colVMName = 1,2  
     if ($totalNoOfRecords -gt 1){
        #Loop to get values from excel file  
        for($i=1;$i -le ($totalNoOfRecords-1);$i++){
            $ResourceGroupName=$Worksheet.Cells.Item($rowNo+$i,$colResourceGroupName).Value
            $VMName=$Worksheet.Cells.Item($rowNo+$i,$colVMName).Value
            Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VMName |select -Property Name,ResourceGroupName,Location
        }    
     }
    }
```

Here is the sample output for reference:

[image]

For more information ,you refer this blog post on **How to Read excel file using [PSExcel Module](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/read-excel-file-using-psexcel-in-powershell2/) in PowerShell**.

Comment: Thankyou for this , it is along the right path of what I need but im still struggling in how to parse the given varibles to the next part of the script,

Comment: Thankyou for this , it is along the right path of what I need but im still struggling in how to parse the given varibles to the next part of the script, I Hve an excel with 3 columns, "Name" "resourcegroup" "location" and have ach row the machine details , I share below the script i am trying to work it complains the varible is invalid .......

Comment: Import-Csv c:\scripts\vmtest.csv | ForEach-Object {
 $resourceGroupName = '$($_.Resourcegroup)' 
$location = '$($_.Location)' 
$vmName = '$($_.Name)'
$snapshotName = '$($_.Name + "-Snapshot"' 
$SnapshotStorage = "Azure-Snapshots" 

$vm = Get-AzVM `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Name $vmName

    $snapshot =  New-AzSnapshotConfig `
    -SourceUri $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.Id `
    -Location $location `
    -CreateOption copy
    New-AzSnapshot `
    -Snapshot $snapshot `
    -SnapshotName $snapshotName `
    -ResourceGroupName $snapshotstorage
}

Comment: @wolfmaster74 - if you have further refinements of your question, these refinements should be *edits to your question*. This should not be posted here. Further: Code (whether PowerShell or otherwise) in comments is pretty much unreadable.